# Как удалить одинаковый элемент для нескольких списков python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, list

Есть несколько списков в Python, пример:

```
list_1 = ['a', 'None', 'b', 'None', 'None', 'c', 'None', 'd']
list_2 = ['a', 'None', 'b', 'c', 'None', 'd', 'None',]
list_3 = ['a', 'None', 'b', 'None', 'None', 'c', 'None', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Не обязательно, чтобы размер у этих списков был одинаковый. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как удалить из нескольких списков значение "None" (да, в нашем списке None это строка) на одинаковых индексах?

Например, в итоге должен остаться лишь такие значения в списках:

```
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'None', 'c', 'd']
list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list_3 = ['a', 'b', 'None', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

В коде эти списки хранятся в словаре.
Пример:

```
some_dict = {
    'key1' = list_1,
    'key2' = list_2,
    'key3' = list_3,
}
```

Пока что не могу сообразить в алгоритм, который тут проще и легче всего применить.
Огромная просьба учитывать наличие самого словаря.
Буду очень признателен за подсказку!

Comment: Что делать в примере `['a', 'None']`, `['b', 'None']`, `['c']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ещё один вариант с [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest). В качестве `fillvalue` используется уникальный объект, что гарантирует корректную работу с любыми данными.

```
import itertools


def clean(lists):
    keys, sources = zip(*lists.items())
    targets = [[] for _ in sources]
    blank = object()
    for v in itertools.zip_longest(*sources, fillvalue=blank):
        if any(map(lambda x: x != 'None', v)):
            for i, t in zip(v, targets):
                if i is not blank:
                    t.append(i)
    return dict(zip(keys, targets))


lists = {
    'key1': ['a', 'None', 'b', 'None', 'None', 'c', 'None', 'd'],
    'key2': ['a', 'None', 'b', 'c', 'None', 'd', 'None'],
    'key3': ['a', 'None', 'b', 'None', 'None', 'c', 'None', 'd', 'e', 'f']
}
result = clean(lists)
```

> ```
> {'key1': ['a', 'b', 'None', 'c', 'd'],
>  'key2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
>  'key3': ['a', 'b', 'None', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Для расширения ассортимента

В коде сделано допущение, что все элементы не приводятся к False

```
from  itertools import zip_longest

result = {}

for v in zip_longest(*some_dict.values(), fillvalue=False):
    if not all(map(lambda x: x == 'None', v)):
        for k, y in zip(some_dict.keys(), v):
            if y:
                result.setdefault(k, []).append(y)

print(*result.values(), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Попробовал Ваш код, отрабатывает именно так, как и необходимо. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Не подскажете, а что не так с кодом у denisnumb? В теории задумка верная должна быть, но 2 подряд None уже ломают её.

Comment: од удаляет элементы в списке по которому делается итерация, соответственно, пропускает элемент

Comment: Кстати, в моем коде сделано допущение, что все элементы не приводятся к False, это надо учитывать

Comment: Извиняюсь, не совсем понял Вас. О чём именно речь?

Comment: в zip_longest `fillvalue=False` означает, что более короткие списки дополняются False до максимальной длины. А потом я проверяю `if y:` чтоб не выводить эти добавленные элементы. Если среди элементов списков могут быть 0, '' и тп надо делать более строгую проверку

Comment: `blank = object()`, `fillvalue=blank`, `if y is not blank:` уберёт зависимость от `False`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy здорово. я не подумал сделать уникальный объект

Comment: Ещё один вариант имеющий право на существование: `fillvalue='None'`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy не уверен, None может и быть

Comment: Вы правы, там возникают трудности. :(

Answer (score 1):

еще вариант для ассортимента:

```
from itertools import compress, zip_longest


filt = [not a==b==c=='None' for a,b,c in zip_longest(*some_dict.values())]
some_dict = {k:list(compress(v, filt)) for k,v in some_dict.items()}

>>> some_dict
'''
{'key1': ['a', 'b', 'None', 'c', 'd'],
 'key2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
 'key3': ['a', 'b', 'None', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']}
```

Comment: `a,b,c` заменить на любое количество списков и будет шоколадка.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант — можно пробежаться циклом `for` сразу по всем трем спискам.

Для этого воспользуемся функцией [**`zip()`**](https://tproger.ru/translations/implementing-zip-list-comprehensions/), а также создадим переменную индекса, с которым в данный момент работаем:

```py
for index, (a, b, c) in enumerate(zip(*some_dict.values())):
   . . .
```

Далее, внутри цикла проверим условие, то что текущий элемент 1, 2 и 3 списка равен `'None'` и, если это так, то удалим текущий индекс из всех трех списков *(при условии, что индекс не выходит за границы списка)*:

```py
for index, (a, b, c) in enumerate(zip(*some_dict.values())):
    if a == b == c == 'None':
        for list_ in (list_1, list_2, list_3):
            if index < len(list_):
                del list_[index]
```

**Если вывести все три списка после этих манипуляций, то на выходе получим результат:**

```py
['a', 'b', 'None', 'c', 'd']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['a', 'b', 'None', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

---

**Полный код:**

```py
some_dict = {
    'key1': ['a', 'None', 'b', 'None', 'None', 'c', 'None', 'd'],
    'key2': ['a', 'None', 'b', 'c', 'None', 'd', 'None',],
    'key3': ['a', 'None', 'b', 'None', 'None', 'c', 'None', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
}

for index, (a, b, c) in enumerate(zip(*some_dict.values())):
    if a == b == c == 'None':
        for list_ in some_dict.values():
            if index < len(list_):
                del list_[index]

print(*some_dict.values(), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Денис, большое спасибо за вариант! К сожалению, прямо сейчас нет возможности запустить фрагмент кода, поэтому, возможно, задам немного глупый вопрос. А почему обновляем счётчик index на каждой итерации? Разве при удалении значения из списка, следующее значение не передвигается на место прошлого? На сколько я понимаю, необходимо увеличивать счётчик только там, где он не находит всех совпадений с "None". Если я пишу глупости, пожалуйста, поправьте меня)

Comment: for index, (a, b, c) in enumerate(zip(*some_dict.values())):

Comment: @splash58 вот так еще круче, сейчас подправлю :)

Comment: @ИванАлексеев если добавить для каждой итерации вывод на экран всех списков, то можно увидеть, что индексы соответствуют нужным значениям

Comment: @denisnumb попробовал вариант, где 2 'None' идут друг за другом, в итоге 1 удаляется, а второй остаётся. По всей видимости это именно то, о чём я говорил выше. Ваш первый вариант с собственным счётчиком, наверное, был правильным, но при этом должен был бы обновляться только там, где он не нашёл всех совпадений с None.